# San Francisco Bay Trail: current map of completed/proposed routes

Tags: trails

This [gap analysis](http://www.baytrail.org/gap-analysis/GAP-ANALYSIS-REPORT-all.pdf) is from 2005.

I want to start biking from Redwood City to San Francisco. I'd rather not bike near cars, which is what [googlemaps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Redwood+City,+CA/San+Francisco+Caltrain+Station,+San+Francisco,+CA/@37.6318463,-122.4707979,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fa03953f35ee1:0xb8e47b9b0baa6a6d!2m2!1d-122.2363548!2d37.4852152!1m5!1m1!1s0x808f7fd6eb33becf:0xb7d880249f5a29f9!2m2!1d-122.394323!2d37.776439!3e1) suggests. and I'd love to bike along the shore.

related: [bike routes around san francisco?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/bike-routes-around-san-francisco), but I also am interested in the timeline for completion.

Comment: Your first link is to the site the runs the trails and they have a trail map.  http://www.baytrail.org/baytrailmap.html

Comment: There are several web sites (e.g. Strava, RideWithGPS, Garmin Connect, MapMyRide) which allow people to publish routes that they have planned/ridden. It is probably worth looking at these sites to see if there is anything "off the shelf" that you can use.

Comment: Blam, that's an answer, not a comment, can you please make it one so this question no longer shows up unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: @joseph_morris But is a  link only answer and I was just admonished for a link only answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your first link is to the site that runs the trails and they have a trail map.
[baytrail.org/baytrailmap](http://baytrail.org/baytrailmap.htm)